# How to turn off script debugger in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, internet-explorer, debugging

Is there a way to turn off script debugging on Visual Studio 2013? I turned off script JIT debugging in Tools>Options>Debugging>JIT. I also turned off script debugging in Internet Explorer. When a script error occurs, there is a option to 'Open Exception Settings'. The error I'm getting is unchecked to 'break when an exception occurs' but VS still breaks. I only get this when using IE. FF and Chrome only show the script error in Firebug/debugger window.

Is there a setting I'm missing to turn this off? I'd rather just use the browser debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Have you double-checked your Debug > Exceptions > JavaScript Runtime Exceptions settings?

[image: Debug > Exceptions screenshot]